# Matplotlib requires sudo on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, matplotlib

I recently shifted to a new laptop. After installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and all of the packages that my previous system contained, I copied all my files from my old system to the new one.

Whenever I try executing any python code that has a matplotlib call, I get the following error

```
File "Q1.py", line 2, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 24, in <module>
import matplotlib.colorbar

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 29, in <module>
import matplotlib.collections as collections

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/collections.py", line 23, in <module>
import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 50, in <module>
import matplotlib.textpath as textpath

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1356, in <module>
_rebuild()

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1343, in _rebuild
pickle_dump(fontManager, _fmcache)

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 939, in pickle_dump
with open(filename, 'wb') as fh:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/matplotlib-skarthikkrishna/fontList.cache'
```

From what I've been able to try, this problem seems to crop up because the code cannot access /tmp/ for writing onto it. The code runs just fine when I add a sudo tag before the execution command.

I'm curious as to why this is happening now. All the packages on my old and new laptop, especially the pyplot package are the same. I haven't missed out on installing any package, nor has there been any update that is not reflected in one of the systems. The code runs just fine in my old laptop. It refuses to work without sudo in the new one. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out on that

**A few details, if they are relevant:**

Both systems run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, last upgraded on 26th Dec, 2014.

I'm running Python 2.7.6 on both systems. [It's a mandated requirement for most of my coursework]

Matplotlib version installed on both systems is 1.3.1

**EDIT :**

The output of ls -ld /tmp/ is

```
drwxrwxrwt 4 root root 4096 Dec 27 18:45 /tmp/
```

The output of ls -ld /tmp/matplotlib-skarthikkrishna is

```
ls: cannot access /tmp/matplotlib-skarthikkrishna: No such file or directory
```

The output remains the same with and without sudo, if at all that is relevant.

Comment: Have you checked if both `/tmp` and `/tmp/matplotlib-skarthikkrishna` have the right read/write/execute permissions? Might be helpful if you add the output of `ls -ld /tmp/` and `ls -ld /tmp/matplotlib-skarthikkrishna` to your question.

Comment: Please don't double post the same question on both Ask Ubuntu Q&A and Stack Overflow.

Comment: How did you install matplotlib? Via `sudo apt-get install matplotlib` or via `pip install matplotlib?`?

Comment: @karel, good catch. See also:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/565903/matplotlib-requires-sudo-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Cel - I've included the results of the command in the question. 

Karel - I'm sorry about that. I didn't realize that stackoverflow and askubuntu were part of the same ecosystem. I won't double post from now on.

jkalden - I used `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` to install matplotlib on both systems

Comment: @KarthikKrishnaSubramanian, you can use '@<username>' in you comments to send a notification to other users. Can you tell us what `python -c "import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.get_configdir())"` prints?

Comment: @cel - I get `/home/skarthikkrishna/.config/matplotlib`

Comment: @KarthikKrishnaSubramanian and `python -c "import matplotlib;pri
int(matplotlib.get_cachedir())"`?

Comment: @cel - I get /tmp/matplotlib-skarthikkrishna

Comment: I am running out of ideas here. At least we know now, that `matplotlib`'s config dir seems reasonable, but for some reason, the cache dir PATH seems weird. A very wild guess would be, that maybe the permissions on `/home/skarthikkrishna/.config/matplotlib` are not correctly set. I would check if your user has read and write permissions in all subdirectories. If that does not help, I am afraid I cannot help anymore. You may want to post a ticket `matplotlib`'s issue tracker at github. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues. The developers are very competent and might know the answer :)

Comment: @cel - Thanks for the link! I've posted an issue at the tracker over at git. I'll post an answer here if I get a solution, so that it can help someone if it happens to them in the future. Thank you everyone for your help on this!

Comment: This is the solution, worked for me: 'sudo rm -rf $HOME/.cache/matplotlib'

Thanks to aberaud commented on Jul 14, 2015 "I had the issue, fixed it by deleting $HOME/.cache/matplotlib that happened to be owned by root." https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3960/

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution, worked for me:

```
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.cache/matplotlib
```

Thanks to aberaud [commented on Jul 14, 2015](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3960/)

> I had the issue, fixed it by deleting $HOME/.cache/matplotlib that happened to be owned by root.